# REST JES Job Completion notification not working

Tags: mainframe, zos, zosmf

I am writing a REST client application, destined to be open source, that submits jobs to JES using zOSMF.  It works but zOSMF doesn't appear to be calling my notification server when the job completes.

This is a page from IBM where I am getting my information:  [Submit a Job](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.izua700/IZUHPINFO_API_PutSubmitJob.htm)

The page describes an optional header:

> **X-IBM-Notification-URL**
> Specifies a destination URL for receiving an HTTP POST when the job is no longer eligible for execution (that is, when the job reaches the output queue or purge queue). The notification is in the form of a JSON document (Content-Type: application/json), which contains job status information. For the contents of the JSON document...

I am setting **X-IBM-Notification-URL** header with this value: "http://my.notification.server:5000/jes/notify"

When I submit jobs using the above header, the job runs successfully. However, "my.notification.server" never receives the callback request.  It's listening on 0.0.0.0.  The z/OS machine and my server are on the same subnet. There are no network or local firewalls in play. The callback URL tests successfully using Postman.

As far as I can tell, zOSMF is never making the call.  I can't seem to locate any log on z/OS that might help explain the behavior.

Am I missing something?  Perhaps there's an issue with zOSMF configuration?  Any help you might offer would be greatly appreciated.